# Disable all scrolling in an iframe, but allow clicking

Tags: css, html, iframe, scroll

I'm trying to disable all forms of scrolling in my iframe, but still allow the user to click a button that appears in the iframe.  I've successfully disabled all forms of scrolling (scroll bars, mouse wheel, etc) by using `scrolling="no"` and `style="pointer-events: none;"`, however the later disables all forms of clicking to.  Is it possible to prevent all forms of scrolling while still allowing the use to click within the iframe to intereact with a button per say?

Edit: Unfortunately I don't have control over the iframe's content :(

Comment: If you have control of the iframe's contents. `html{overflow:hidden}` should do it.

Comment: Or check out these other scrollbar options: http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Unfortunately I don't have control over the iframe's contents :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete `style="pointer-events: none;"` and just make the height of the iframe the height of the document inside of it. If there are objects inside of the iframe that scroll, and the iframe is coming from a domain that is not your own, I'm sorry to say that you are out of luck. You cannot effect the contents of an iframe that is not hosted on your own domain.