# iframe, allowing clicking but disable scrolling

Tags: iframe, scroll, click

This is a duplicate question of [Disable all scrolling in an iframe, but allow clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393393/disable-all-scrolling-in-an-iframe-but-allow-clicking) but I'm going to risk asking it again because that question was asked in 2014 and no solution was found (except that it can't be done). I'm desperately trying to find out if this can be done now. Therefore I would like to post this question again:

I'm trying to disable all forms of scrolling in my iframe, but still allow the user to click a button that appears in the iframe. I've successfully disabled all forms of scrolling (scroll bars, mouse wheel, etc) by using scrolling="no" and style="pointer-events: none;", however the later disables all forms of clicking to. Is it possible to prevent all forms of scrolling while still allowing the use to click within the iframe to inter-act with a button?

Unfortunately I don't have control over the iframe's content.

Possibly there is a way how to do this now after so many years? If so, I'd be very happy to hear about it. I checked all kinds of similar question of clicking and scrolling iframes but I did not find a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Honestly, I've never tried that.

But I imagine you could put a div over the suface of the iframe (as if it was a transparent overlay), and then when the user clicks the invisible div (that is on the iframe) then triggering a click event on the iframe?

If you happen to need the click's coordinates then make sure the div has got the exact same dimensions of the iframe (but with less z-index, so you make sure it's ON it) and then pass the div's click event coords to the iframe's click event you are gonna trigger.

Let me know if this works!

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I abandoned this project. I could not make it work... :(